# Как исправить тень?

Tags: three.js

Создал один большой плоский квадрат и на него поставил куб. Куб должен отбрасывать тень на квадрат. Поставил и настроил источник света: `directionalLight.castShadow = true;`. Добавил на куб `cube.castShadow = true;` и на квадрат `ground.receiveShadow = true;`, но получил очень странную тень:
[image: Странная тень]

Что я сделал не так?

Comment: воспроизводимый фрагмент с проблемой получиться вставить сюда?

Comment: В итоге сам разобрался - оказалось, что источник света был слишком маленький и поэтому давал такую тень.

Comment: Это замечательно )

Comment: хорошо бы добавить ответ с кодом, решающим проблему )